# Meteor [Error: Can't wait without a fiber] after a call to Email.send

Tags: meteor, callback, timeout, fiber

I've created a very simple server using Meteor, to send an email after a timeout. When I use a timeout, the message is successfully sent but an error is thrown: `[Error: Can't wait without a fiber]`.

Here's my code:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // <DUMMY VALUES: PLEASE CHANGE>
    process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtp://me%40example.com:PASSWORD@smtp.example.com:25';
    var to = 'you@example.com'
    var from = 'me@example.com'
    // </DUMMY>
    // 
    var subject = 'Message'
    var message = "Hello Meteor"

    var eta_ms = 10000
    var timeout = setTimeout(sendMail, eta_ms);
    console.log(eta_ms)

    function sendMail() {
      console.log("Sending...")
      try {
        Email.send({
          to: to,
          from: from,
          subject: subject,
          text: message
        })
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Email.send error:", error)
      }
    }
  })
}
```

I understand that I could use `Meteor.wrapAsync` to create a fiber. But `wrapAsync` expects there to be a callback to call, and `Email.send` doesn't use a callback.

What should I do to get rid of the error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This happens because while your `Meteor.startup` function runs inside a Fiber (like almost all other Meteor callbacks), the `setTimeout` you use does not! Due to the nature of `setTimeout` it will run on the top scope, outside the fiber in which you defined and/or called the function.

To solve, you could use something like `Meteor.bindEnvironment`:

```
setTimeout(Meteor.bindEnvironment(sendMail), eta_ms);
```

And then do so for every single call to `setTimeout`, which is a painfully hard fact.
Good thing it's not actually true. Simply use [`Meteor.setTimeout`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_settimeout) instead of the native one:

```
Meteor.setTimeout(sendMail, eta_ms);
```

From the docs:

> These functions work just like their native JavaScript equivalents. If you call the native function, you'll get an error stating that Meteor code must always run within a Fiber, and advising to use `Meteor.bindEnvironment`

Meteor timers just [`bindEnvironment` then delay the call](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/832e6fe44f3635cae060415d6150c0105f2bf0f6/packages/meteor/timers.js#L16) as you wanted.